# Member since today or...?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

[image]

Probably there is something wrong with script on user profile page:

Should I report this somewhere or is this expected?

Comment: It was a bug, but [a fix should be rolled out now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253944/member-since-bug).